SonarQube community edition SSO
I am trying to set up SonarQube Community Edition to use SSO. I have tried configuring SAML with Azure AD. The issue I am facing is that I can access the SonarQube interface, but the permissions are not the same as when connecting through LDAP. This means that assigning rights via groups (group mapping) is not working correctly.
Any ideas?
